# Convert LSTM Graph with TFLite Fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, toco

Folks, I have an error whenever I try to convert my LSTM graph to TFLite:

```
user@user:~/tensorflow/tensorflow$ bazel run --config=opt   //tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco --   --input_file=/home/user/model/rnn/lstm_graph_mobilnet_v2_100_128.pb   --output_file=/home/user/model/rnn/lstm_graph_mobilnet_v2_100_128.tflite   --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF   --output_format=TFLITE   --inference_type=FLOAT   --input_shape=1,10,2560   --input_array=input/x_input   --output_array=output/y_pred
WARNING: ignoring http_proxy in environment.
.......................
WARNING: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/9944cfee49d745019014aac0edc80315/external/protobuf_archive/WORKSPACE:1: Workspace name in /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/9944cfee49d745019014aac0edc80315/external/protobuf_archive/WORKSPACE (@com_google_protobuf) does not match the name given in the repository's definition (@protobuf_archive); this will cause a build error in future versions
INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco (84 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco
INFO: Elapsed time: 88.490s, Critical Path: 35.68s
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action

INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco '--input_file=/home/user/model/rnn/lstm_graph_mobilnet_v2_100_128.pb' '--output_file=/home/users/model/rnn/lstm_graph_mobilnet_v2_100_128.tflite' '--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF' '--output_format=TFLITE' '--inference_type=FLOAT' '--input_shape=1,10,2560' '--input_array=input/x_input' '--output_array=output/y_pred'
2018-07-10 16:38:59.794308: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:822] Check failed: d >= 1 (0 vs. 1)
```

During inference, batch size = 1, 10 inputs, each input is of length 2560

Why are my dimensions 0 in d >=1 (0 vs. 1)?

Any sample projects that convert RNN to TFLite?

Comment: Right now there isn't an easy tutorial. We're working on improving tooling and providing a tutorial.

Comment: @aselle, this method worked for me in terms of conversion. I just have not tested it on a phone yet. I also noticed that quantized 8UINT conversion is not supported, so when I convert it, it ends up being a FLOAT type. Let's see how fast this will work on a smartphone's CPU (I do not own a Pixel, so I can only use my CPU):
 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15805#issuecomment-407298717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method worked for me:
[LSTM pb to tflite](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15805#issuecomment-407298717)

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue,
I was using tflearn api on the top of Tensorflow.
While converting tensorflow model to tflite format, I got few errors.

I retrained the model by removing dropout parameter from lstm layer, and my model could convert to tflite format.

Before code:

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.embedding(net, input_dim=len(train_x[0]), output_dim=64)
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 16, dropout=0.4)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax', name='output_layer')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
```

After code:

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.embedding(net, input_dim=len(train_x[0]), output_dim=64)
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 16)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax', name='output_layer')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
```

But I don't think removing dropout parameter is a good idea, it is just a hack. If your model performs well without having dropout option then only this hack will work.